# Setting an Endpoint in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I currently have a SoapUI project which I intend to have executed periodically (every 5 minutes) in Jenkins. I've completed the following thus far:

1. Created the relevant directory in the Workspace i.e `workspace\SOA\SOAProject\src\test\soapui\SoapUIProject.xml`
2. I've configured a pom.xml which sits in the `SOAProject` folder alongside the `src` folder
3. I've created a Jenkins job (I've chosen a Maven project, although it should not be an issue if I had chosen a freestyle job)

My question is, how do I set the endpoint?
I've done the following...

**Build**

```
**Root POM**        pom.xml
```

**Goals and options**

```
       testrunner.bat -e0.00.0.006:8040
```

Edit:
I've installed the EnvInject plugin. I'm not sure how to create the /properties file and what to put in their in order to set the execution environment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but my suggestion is to get it running via command-line first. Once you figure out how to launch it without Jenkins, having Jenkins issue the same command because easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a Maven project, there is a useful plugin to set the endpoint and different propeties for the testSuites...
https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin